# Google Account access token

Tags: gwt, oauth

How to extend life time of google account access token i used gwt-oauth2-0.2 to obtain an access token but problem is that it expires very soon .i want to get a token with extended life time preferably that does not expires.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is GWT code, it's executed in the client using client-side JavaScript.  It is not possible to get a long-lived access token from within client-side JavaScript.  The issued tokens last 60 minutes currently-- and you can always get another token later without any user interaction (as the user has already approved the OAuth grant request).  This should be sufficient for all client-side access to a user's data.

If you're comfortable using server-side code instead, you could use the [OAuth 2.0 flow for server-side web applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer), and specify [`access_type=offline`](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline).  This gives you an authorization code passed as a query parameter-- you then make a server-to-server call to exchange the authorization code for an access token.  The first time you exchange a code for a given user, you'll also get a refresh token.  Although the access token will expire, the refresh token can be used indefinitely to obtain new access tokens for that user by simply making a server-to-server call.

Comment: "you can always get another token later without any user interaction" : when I try to get an access token with oauth2-0.2, it opens up a popup window. So even though user has already approved the grant request, it will still open a pop up window and close immediately. Is there a way to bypass this?